# Thermopile (ZTP-135SR) Circuit Diagram Question

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image: Data sheet Schematic/Diagram]

Is \$V_\mathrm{th}\$ being inputted into/through (as a junction/node) negative thermopile lead? (See Schematic with highlighted section)

I'm confused to why you would need to amplify \$V_\mathrm{th}\$ (Voltage of thermistor).
I understand you need to amplify for Vthermopile, since the voltage is very small.

I appreciate any help. 
If you need any more information let me know.

*Edit 1*: The thermistor is used to measure the ambient temperature. I believe to solve for voltage out the thermopile you use
$$
V=S(T_\mathrm{tmp}^B-T_\mathrm{th}^B).
$$
The thermistor for this model is inside the thermopile. As far as I know, the thermistor and thermopile have + and - lead (Four leads total). 
I believe Vth is just a reference value.
I'm not sure if that is correct to say that.

*Edit 2*: According to the circuit diagram on the datasheet, the thermistor voltage will be amplified. I'm not sure that's necessary for all thermopile models.

Thanks!

Data sheet for reference: https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/18/AAS-920-159D-ZTP-135SR-031314-web-1315865.pdf

Comment: does the thermistor provide some temperature compensation?

Comment: @analogsystemsrf Hopefully my edit will be able to answer your question.